# Passing a closure causing a memory leak

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function:

```
func attachToComment(_ data: Data, url: URL?, type: MediaType) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let image = UIImage(data: data)!
    model.attachmentData = data
    model.attachmentVideoURL = url
    model.attachmentType = type

    toolbar.attachImage(image, withType: type)
}
```

This is passed a reference to a View Controller that is presented modally:

```
containerNavViewController.attachToComment = attachToComment
```

`ContainerNavViewController` is a `UINavigationController` that has a container view controller inside it. This shows the camera and once the image is taken, passes the `attachToComment` function to the next view controller – `EditImageViewController`. Inside ContainerNavViewController I have the following code:

```
var attachToComment: ((_ data: Data, _ url: URL?, _ type: MediaType) -> ())?
var model = CameraModel()
....

editImageViewController.attachToComment = self.attachToComment
editImageViewController.model = model
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editImageViewController, animated: false)
```

Inside EditImageViewController I have the following code that calls the closure:

```
attachToComment(model.imageData, model.videoURL, model.mediaType)
```

This then calls the original function and dismisses the modal view controller. However, deinit is not called on these views, and they're very much "living" in the background. Where is my memory leak and how can I prevent it?

Comment: It looks like you might have a retain cycle going on. Self strongly owns attachToComment (closures are first-class objects), inside the closure you reference self and variables owned by self (model, toolbar, and the function dismiss). As a result, self owns the closure, the closure strongly captures self and neither will now ever deallocate because they retain each other reciprocally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dare and Sealos both suggest, the problem is likely a strong reference cycle. But the code provided in the question, alone, is not enough to cause such a cycle (because when you dismiss `editImageViewController`, if there are no more strong references to it, the closure is released and the strong reference cycle is broken).

A few observations, though:

1. I was unable to reproduce your strong reference cycle solely using the provided code.

   But I can induce a strong reference cycle if the view controller that presented `editImageViewController` is keeping a strong reference to it, preventing it from being released. Is `editImageViewController` a local variable, or is it a property? If a property, change it to a local variable and that may resolve the issue. Or perhaps something else is keeping a strong reference to `editImageViewController` (e.g. a repeating timer or something like that).

   You can identify what is keeping a strong reference to `editImageViewController` using the "Debug Memory Graph" tool (see point 3, below).
2. If you did want to make sure that the `attachToComment` of `EditImageViewController` didn't keep a strong reference to the presenting view controller, I would replace:

   ```
   editImageViewController.attachToComment = attachToComment
   ```

   with:

   ```
   editImageViewController.attachToComment = { [weak self] data, url, type in
       self?.attachToComment(data, url: url, type: type)
   }
   ```

   That's the simplest way to make sure the `attachToComment` closure in `editImageViewController` doesn't maintain a strong reference to the presenting view controller.
3. You might want to use the "Debug Memory Graph" tool in Xcode 8 to identify the ownership of the `EditImageViewController`. For example, I did an example where I both:

   - Incorrectly stored `editImageViewController` as a property of the presenting view controller rather than keeping it as a local variable (point 1); and
   - Didn't use the `weak` pattern in the closure (point 2).

   When I did that, I got an memory graph like so:

   [image: object graph]

   From that graph, I don't have to guess what the source of the problem is. I can see not only that the strong reference cycle exists, but what specifically is causing the problem. If I fix either of the two above issues (or both), though, this cycle disappears.

Comment: Everyone here gave excellent answers! Point 1 was the answer for me. I had a strong reference to `containerNavViewController` which was a property (which in turn had strong references to the other controllers). Setting this to nil upon dismissal deinited everything correctly. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you assign attachToComment, it captures the self pointer of the view controller, and that prevents the release.

There are 2 ways you can solve this:

1. When the views are dismissed, nil the attachToComment variable.

EDIT Because of Rob's correction, instead of capturing an instance, get back a closure with a weak self-pointer:

2. Use a weak self-pointer in the attachToComment variable. Like so:

   ```
   typealias ReturnType = (Data, URL?, MediaType) -> ()
   func attachToComment() -> ReturnType {

       return { [weak self] in
           self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           let image = UIImage(data: data)!
           self?.model.attachmentData = data
           self?.model.attachmentVideoURL = url
           self?.model.attachmentType = type

           self?.toolbar.attachImage(image, withType: type)
       }
   }

   editImageViewController.attachToComment = containerNavController.attachToComment()
   ```

The thing is, this is usually done using weak protocols. An example of that would be:

```
protocol EditImageProtocol: class {
    func attachToComment(_ data: Data, url: URL?, type: MediaType)
}

class ContainerNavController: EditImageProtocol {
    func attachToComment(_ data: Data, url: URL?, type: MediaType) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let image = UIImage(data: data)!
        model.attachmentData = data
        model.attachmentVideoURL = url
        model.attachmentType = type

        toolbar.attachImage(image, withType: type)
    }
}

class EditImageViewController {
    weak var delegate: EditImageProtocol?

    func someFunction() {
        delegate?.attachToComment(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot, now I have actually tested this before submitting!